# add custom formatter for checkbox column when multiselect option is set to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid as grid with multiselect:true property. I want to remove checkbox for some rows based on some row value(disable/do not allow to check). I want to add formatter on checkbox model to remove checkbox on that column

I tried to access colModel inside beforeProcessing but i dont see the column name 'cb' autoadded by jqgrid yet. hence i cannot inject formatter inside the colmodel for 'cb'.

```
jqGrid({
  multiselect: true,
  beforeSelectRow: function() {
     //called when tried to select one row.
     //its not called when selectAll is called.
  },
  onSelectAll: function(rowids, status) {
     //gets selected row ids when status is true
  }
})
```

1) I want to manipulate selection of checkboxes based on row Value.

2) checkbox should not be (visible/selectable) if row with column isApplicable=false

jgrid version: 5.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important that you always include **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) in the text of your question. It's important to know **the fork** of jqGrid too ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Free jqGrid fork, which I develop, contains some options/callbacks which can be used to implement your requirements.

First of all you can use `hasMultiselectCheckBox` callback to inform jqGrid in which rows (based on the content from `isApplicable` column for example) multiselect checkbox should be created:

```
hasMultiselectCheckBox: : function (options) {
    // options is object like below
    // { rowid: rowid, iRow: irow, iCol: pos, data: item, checked: checked };
    // one can use options.data to examine the data of the current row

    return options.data != null && options.data.isApplicable;
}
```

Even if the checkbox not exist in the row one can still select the row by clicking on the row. (By the way, you can use `multiselectPosition: "none"` to have no column with multiselect checkboxs at all.) Thus you should add `beforeSelectRow` callback additionally, which prevent selection of the rows having `isApplicable` equal to `false`:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);

    if (item != null && !item.isApplicable) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
},
```

alternatively, if you use one of the latest version of free jqGrid, you can use `rowattr` to add `"jqgskipselect"` class to rows, which should be not selectable:

```
rowattr: function (item) {
    if (!item.isApplicable) {
        return { "class": "jqgskipselect" };
    }
},
```

free jqGrid prevent selection of rows, which have the class. In old versions you can use disabled class instead for preventing selection. It's `"ui-state-disabled"` class in case of usage jQuery UI CSS or `"disabled"` class in case of usage Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: I tried rowattr already. But the real problem lies on selectAll. even if i skip the checkbox.selectAll will by default return all visible rows.
it wont skip not applicable checkboxes. always return all records.
$('gridid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')

Comment: @MayurPatil: You added at the end of your question that you use **commercial** Guriddo jqGrid 5.3.0. It doesn't support `hasMultiselectCheckBox` or `jqgskipselect`. So you have the problem in `selectAll` because usage of the fork which don't support `jqgskipselect` class. I wrote that you can use disabled class instead of `jqgskipselect` (`ui-state-disabled` or `disabled`) depend on CSS Framework, which you use.